# Use Azure Key Vault to get secrets

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-identity, azure-secrets

I want to use Azure Key Vault in a ML notebook to retrieve secrets. The tutorial I followed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-python) suggested to use

```py
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

vault_url = 'https://<myvaulturl>.vault.azure.net'
az_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = SecretClient(vault_url=vault_url, credential=az_credential)

client.get_secret('<mysecret>')
```

However I get this error `ClientAuthenticationError: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. Attempted credentials: EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. ManagedIdentityCredential: Unexpected response 'None'`.
I think it does depend on the fact that I don't have my environment variables set:

```
AZURE_CLIENT_ID
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
AZURE_TENANT_ID
```

I was wondering if there was any other way to access the vault without using the `DefaultAzureCredential` class.
Anybody has any idea?

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `ClientSecretCredential` to do this :

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

AZURE_TENANT_ID = ''
AZURE_CLIENT_ID = ''
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET = ''


cred = ClientSecretCredential(
    client_id = AZURE_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret = AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    tenant_id = AZURE_TENANT_ID
)

keyVaultName = ''
KVUri = f"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net"

sc = SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=cred)
print(sc.get_secret('<secret name>').value)
```

Result:
[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

1. You can find your tenant ID here on Azure Portal:

[image]

2. Follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal) to create an Azure AD app and follow [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret) to create an app secret. so that you have all 3 params(tenant id, client id and client secret) for `ClientSecretCredential`
3. Follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal) to add this app to the access policy so that this app has permission to query secrets in Azure Key vault.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I am new to Azure I am not that sure how to retrieve those parameters. You able to give me a hint? Thanks

Comment: @3nomis, sure, I have appended the steps in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch and write all secrets via azure cli in Mac, i call the below script: `sh keyvault-list.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 
echo "Enter the keyvault Name to be used for printing secrets:"
read keyvaultName
 
 
fileName=$keyvaultName+$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S").txt
echo "Starting secret printing for $keyvaultName to fileName=$fileName"
echo "Starting secret printing for  $keyvaultName!" >> $fileName
 
 
keyvaultEntries=($(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $keyvaultName --query "[*].{name:name}" -o tsv))
 
for i in "${keyvaultEntries[@]}"
do
    # do whatever on "$i" here
    echo "$i"  ::  "$(az keyvault secret show --name $i --vault-name $keyvaultName -o tsv --query value)"
    echo "$i"  ::  "$(az keyvault secret show --name $i --vault-name $keyvaultName -o tsv --query value)" >> $fileName
done
```